# Liferay comparator not working

Tags: sorting, liferay, article

I am using method for finding structure articles:

```
List<JournalArticle> articles = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getStructureArticles(groupId, "15566", 0, 10000, comparator);
```

comparator is instance of class:

```
public class OrderByEventsStartDate extends OrderByComparator{  
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){  
    System.out.println("comparator test");  
    return 1;  
}  
}
```

Message is never printed and results are not sorted... Any help, please?

Comment: one possibility is, return resultset can be of size 0, and hence no comparator will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> results are not sorted...

Because you are always returning `1`.

Now to create an `OrderByComparator` you need to do something more.

If you look at the [source code as to how the `OrderByComparator`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/service/persistence/impl/BasePersistenceImpl.java#L431) is used by the different persistence methods you would get some idea.

Also a look at some of Liferay's implemented Comparators will shed some light as to what you need to do:

1. [Journal Comparators](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portlet/journal/util/comparator) - You can check the [`ArticleTitleComparator`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portlet/journal/util/comparator/ArticleTitleComparator.java)
2. [UserFirstNameComparator](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/util/comparator/UserFirstNameComparator.java)

#### A super-short tutorial on implementing `OrderByComparator` in liferay

1. You would require to create 3 fields:

   1. `public static final String ORDER_BY_ASC` - Specifies the field with which you want to order the results. In the ascending manner.
   2. `public static final String ORDER_BY_DESC` - Specifies the field with which you want to order the results. In descending order.
   3. `public static final String[] ORDER_BY_FIELDS` - Specifies the different fields required for sorting (refer `UserFirstNameComparator` for multiple fields).
2. Implement the `compare` method on the field you would like to sort
3. Impement the `getOrderBy()` method - refer `ArticleTitleComparator`
4. Impement the `getOrderByFields()` method - refer `ArticleTitleComparator`
5. Impement the `isAscending()` method, required in `compare` and `getOrderBy` methods to decide whether it is asc or desc - refer `ArticleTitleComparator`

> Message is never printed and

Because you have not implemented these methods, it ignores the `OrderByComparator` you have passed. You can check the source code of the method you are using [`JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl#getStructureArticles`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/impl/JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java#L3017)

Hope this helps.